# ngCordovaOauth for Instagram - Invalid scope field

Tags: angularjs, cordova, oauth, ionic-framework, ngcordova

**SOLVED!**

I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.ionic.io/oauth-ionic-ngcordova/) to create my own Ionic based Instagram Feed app. I use [this ngCordovaOauth plugin](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth) to help me with the Oauth part.

But, I get stucked at this screen after login into my Instagram account.

[image]

This is my **app.js** so far:

```
var app = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova']);

app.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
        }
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
});

app.controller('OauthCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaOauth', function($scope, $cordovaOauth) {

    $scope.login = function() {
        var igClientId = "example123456789";
        $cordovaOauth.instagram(igClientId, ["scope=basic"]).then(function(result) {
            alert.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        }, function(error) {
            alert.log(error);
        });
    };

}]);
```

I also try to empty the [scope](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) array like this:

```
$cordovaOauth.instagram(igClientId, [])
```

But it didn't work too.

Btw, this is my redirect URL inside my Instagram Client section:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Solved. What I did:

1. Download latest ngCordovaOuth script.
2. Untick the "Disable implicit OAuth" checkbox inside my IG Client setting.

My final login function looks like this:

```
$scope.login = function() {
        var igClientId = "example123456789";
        $cordovaOauth.instagram(igClientId, ["scope=basic"]).then(function(result) {
            var r = JSON.stringify(result);
            $scope.result = r;
        }, function(error) {
            var e = error;
            $scope.result = e;
        });
    };
```

https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/issues/133